# bash script to identify the files based on current date and file name pattern

Tags: bash, shell-script

bash script to identify the files based on current date and file name pattern .

There are 10 files located in different directory which contains date pattern in it . I need to pick these files one by one and send to remote site .

I thought to list the file naming pattern, location in config file and pick from the script but without any luck . Someone help

sample file name patter and location .

> /documents/accounts/abc_yyyy-mm-dd.txt
>
> /documents/namelist/def_yyyy-mm-dd-txt
>
> /documents/newcustomer/ghijkl_yyyy-mm-dd-txt

```
date=`date +%Y-%m-%d`;
config_file="/scripts/config/abc.cfg";
echo $config_file;
URL="http://localhost:9200/document-$date";

while read var value
do
    "$var"= curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/documents-'$date'/document/ 
done < /path/to/abc.config
```

to pick these files daily and send it to remote site using curl everyday once all the files are available .

Comment: Could you please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/333011/edit) your question to show some examples of inputs and the desired outcome, along with what you've tried and what about it didn't work the way you wanted it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this files

```
[leonardo4it@box4it tst] $ ll -R /home/leonardo4it/tst/*
/home/leonardo4it/tst/abc:
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 leonardo4it leonardo4it 0 Dec 28 14:04 abc_2016-12-28.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 leonardo4it leonardo4it 0 Dec 28 14:34 excluded.txt

/home/leonardo4it/tst/shhh:
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 leonardo4it leonardo4it 0 Dec 28 14:06 hbcinema_2016-12-28.txt

/home/leonardo4it/tst/u111:
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 leonardo4it leonardo4it 0 Dec 28 14:06 uu_2016-12-28.txt
```

once built the date of the day use **find** like above. I get this list

```
[leonardo4it@box4it tst] $ export dat_day=(`date +%Y-%m-%d`)
[leonardo4it@box4it tst] $ echo $dat_day
2016-12-28
[leonardo4it@box4it tst] $ find /home/leonardo4it/tst/ -type f -name "*$dat_day.txt"
/home/leonardo4it/tst/abc/abc_2016-12-28.txt
/home/leonardo4it/tst/shhh/hbcinema_2016-12-28.txt
/home/leonardo4it/tst/u111/uu_2016-12-28.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
find /documents/ -type f -name "*${date}.txt" | while read filename
do
       echo "filename : ${filename}"
       #  put your transfer logic here...
done
```

Comment: It did not work .

Comment: It did not work . no results from find command , if i use simply *.txt then it gives everything from the documents folder

Comment: `#!/bin/bash
date=`date +%Y-%m-%d`;
config_file="/scripts/config/abc.cfg"; 
echo $config_file; 
URL="http://localhost:9200/document-$date";
find /documents -type f -name "*_'${date}'*.csv" | while read filename
do
       echo "filename : ${filename}"
       var=$(base64 $filename| perl -pe 's/\n//g');
       var1= curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/documents-'$date'/document/?pipeline=attachment&pretty' -d' { "data" : "'$var'" }')  
done;`

Comment: why you includ single quote here.. '${date}'